# Upload preset must be specified when using unsigned upload - Swift/iOS

Tags: image, post, upload, alamofire, cloudinary

I'll try to keep this simple. Unsigned uploading is ENABLED. I'm using the below link to simply upload a photo I take from my iPhone app to the "Media Library" section of Cloudinary. In the link, I did put my Cloud Name.

https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUD NAME/image/upload/

I'm using AlamoFire to upload the photo and the error I get is below. Where can I include the upload present key that was provided? In the link? They want it in code?

```
["error": {

    message = "Upload preset must be specified when using unsigned upload";

}]
```

Comment: Here is a sample code for unsigned upload :                                                                 let params = CLDUploadRequestParams().setUploadPreset("sample_preset").setPublicId("my_dog").setFolder("my_folder/my_sub_folder/")
       .setResourceType("image"))
let request = cloudinary.createUploader().upload(file: fileUrl, params: params)                   Please note that you'll need to create an unsigned upload preset and add it to your upload call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code for unsigned upload :

```
let params = CLDUploadRequestParams().setUploadPreset("sample_preset").setPublicId("my_dog").setFolder("my_folder/my_sub_folder/") .setResourceType("image")) let request = cloudinary.createUploader().upload(file: fileUrl, params: params)
```

Please note that you'll need to create an unsigned upload preset and add it to your upload call.